# find partial derivative of the function

Tags: derivatives, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I have this equation which is basically a maximum likelihood equation for EM-algorithm.
$$L(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n{\ln{(\sum_{j=1}^kw_jp_j(x_i;\theta_j))}}$$
I'm trying to derive a partial derivative by $\theta_j$ from it.
What I'm getting is:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n{w_j\over p(x_i)}\frac{\partial p_j(x_i;\theta_j)}{\partial \theta_j}$$
where $$p(x_i)=\sum_{j=1}^kw_jp_j(x_i;\theta_j)$$
This derivative should be equal to 0 and I can multiply it by $p_j(x_i;\theta_j)$ and get
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_j} = \sum_{i=1}^n{w_jp_j(x_i;\theta_j)\over p(x_i)}\frac{\partial p_j(x_i;\theta_j)}{\partial \theta_j}=\frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^n g_{ij}p_j(x_i;\theta_j)}{\partial \theta_j}=0$$
Which is almost as it should be. But the problem is that I somewhere miss the logarithm as it should look like this:
$$\frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^n g_{ij}\ln p_j(x_i;\theta_j)}{\partial \theta_j}=0$$
Where am I wrong?

$g_{ij}={w_jp_j(x_i;\theta_j)\over p(x_i)}$ which is obtained in the first step of the EM-algorithm.

Comment: What are the $g_{i j}$ in the "answer"?

Comment: @coffeemath added clarification into the question.

Comment: You multiply and **divide** by $p_j(x_i;\theta_j)$.

Comment: @MathLover no. Only multiply. Added clarification that this derivative should be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not because your derivative is zero that you can multiply all the terms in your summation by different weights $p_j(x_i;\theta_j)$ (they are different because they change with $x_i$). You should as mentioned by Math Lover, multiply and divide by $p_j(x_i;\theta_j)$ and get
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta_j}(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n{w_jp_j(x_i;\theta_j)\over p(x_i)}\frac{1}{p_j(x_i;\theta_j)} \frac{\partial p_j(x_i;\theta_j)}{\partial \theta_j}=\frac{\partial \sum_{i=1}^n g_{ij}\log(p_j(x_i;\theta_j))}{\partial \theta_j}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Stupid mistake.